# How to test server under heavy network traffic?

Tags: networking, http, network-traffic, stress-testing

I need to test our server infrastructure providing static content, under heavy traffic. I need to utilize 10GBps at minimum if our new CDN infrastructure is working correctly, or pinout bottlenecks. Our CDNs are providing content by HTTP / HTTPS protocols, so we need to test those.

Is there any solution or provider of such service? What is the easiest way to setup test like this? I only found local application which are generating traffic but its not enough. And lending cloud capacity and test it from there is my last option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Server Fault is...not about...Product, service, or learning material recommendations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Best would be to generate the traffic from cloud vendors. I pretty sure with a couple of VPS and bench apps you will be able to test performance. Just remember to have your graphing ready before you start and when running tests to run them at intervals 10%,15%,20% load and so on. Then you also need to graph respond times as load increases.

Comment: can you recommend any provider? with easy and quick setup?

Comment: I think amazon cloud services would be your best bet as you pay per cpu time, so you can run your tests and only be billed for the time you use. With amazon ready made linux images you can quick have those servers up and running, then you just install siege or any other tool that you would like to stress test with and off you go. Lastly you will need to do some scripting to make your life easier for starting and stopping the tests.

Comment: well this was my last option, but i guess i have no other option than this. Thanks

Comment: Basically 10Gbps worth of traffic is an insane amount :) so you will need plenty of vms. I will as a test, try and see how much you can generate from one vm using siege, then you can calculate on how much vms you do require.